# Solving the inverse square law differential equation without components

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Is there any way to solve Newton's law differential equation for a satellite in orbit, both for position and velocity.

The solution for both for position and velocity might be able to be written in complex exponential form : $r = r_1 e^{i\omega_1 t}+r_2 e^{i\omega_1 t}$, I believe these are called epicycles of Ptolemy . I'm interested using this as a solution to the Newton's differential equation for an inverse square law of a satellite in orbit subject to initial conditions .

Comment: please use mathjax

Comment: Satellites in orbit do not see the simple inverse square law only but also the most important multipolar corrections due to the non-sphericity of Earth. What are you looking for? An analytic or a numerical solution?

Comment: Since you have a functional form of the position, $r$, take the second time derivative (i.e., $\ddot{r}=\mathrm{d}^2r/\mathrm{d}t^2$) and see if it can be matched to the gravitational force.

Comment: An analytic solution. Doest have to be a satellite ,any body moving in an inverse square law.